How to change Intelli-J theme back to what it was
I haven't opened this app for a long time. This color theme is really bad. I do not know if this is just my problem or a general one.
How do I bring back the old orange dark theme?
This is what my IDE currently looks like:


Does this answer your question? How to reset IntelliJ IDEA settings?
